# checking string presence in nested loop

Tags: python, loops, break

I am writing on function which trying to extract the user name from Resume.

Most of the time first line contains username but sometime also my students write Resume, CV title in first line. So I want to ignore such line and check for the next line.

IF line without skip words within first four line of resume occurs, then consider it as a person name

```
def name_extractor(self, text):
    skip_words = ['CURRICULUM', 'VITAE', 'resume']
    text_lines = text.split('\n')
    name = ''
    # pdb.set_trace()        
    for  i in range(0,4):
        if text_lines[i]:
            for word in skip_words:
                if word.lower() in text_lines[i]:
                    break
                else:
                    name = text.split('\n')[i]
                    # print name
                    return name         
    return name
```

Here I tried to write the logic but it is not correctly working. If there is first line as resume, even it gives the name as resume.

How can I skip any begining lines which have any word from skip_list and print the correct name.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas: sorry, updated the question. please let me know if still not clear

Comment: Examples of files you're searching the names in,  would be helpful in producing better code!

Comment: Why are you checking the first 4 lines? You said the username is in the first line if the `skip_words` are not there and in the second line otherwise.

Comment: @nutmeg64: sometime first line is as "resume" then few news line and then name. That is why I have put threshold for four line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason your code is not working the way you expect is that the function returns as soon as any one of the skip_words are not in a line of text.

You need help with fundamentals more than an answer to this question. Try pasting your code into pythontutor.com and watching execution line by line.

- Your code is not using (nor needing) an object-oriented approach. The `self` parameter is used when your function `def` is a method defined within a `class`. The fact that you never use `self` in your function definition is a sign that you proabably can just write a regular function definition, outside of a class definition. Remove the `self` parameter.
- You are not comparing lower case to lower case. Your code transforms the hard-coded list's items to lower case, but the text parameter remains with case as-is. Use lower case in your `skip_words` constant and call `lower` on the text passed to the function rather than calling `lower` on the constant.
- Python code is generally more readable if you iterate across list elements themselves. Use a variable to represent each element rather than a counter to access list elements. This would also eliminate the need for the `if` statement you use to check for existence of the first four lines.
- It's usually best to use only one `return` statement in a function.
- `break` will exit the `for` loop, and I think you intend `continue` which will skip the rest of the for loop and advance to the next iteration.

  ```
  def name_extractor(text):
      skip_words = ['curriculum', 'vitae', 'resume']
      text_lines = text.split('\n')
      for line in text_lines[:4]:
          line_words = set(line.lower().split(' '))
          if not line_words.intersection(skip_words):
              return line
      return ''
  ```